Removing common values from nested numpy array in python
I have two numpy array "point" and "r". These array contains coordinates of point cloud [[x y z]]. Now i need to remove the values of "r" from "point". I cannot do a for loop because i have thousands of coordinates and this take a lot of time. I tried using the numpy isin method but the problem it seems is that it also remove values where only one of the three dimension match inside the array. I need to remove point where all the x y z matches in both array.
There is no problem in the "r" array. if i just save the "r" array i get all the point that should be inside "r" but when i run this np.isin method then point that should not be remove also gets removed.
r = np.array([[x y z]])
point = np.vstack((las.x, las.y, las.z)).transpose()
non_building_mask = ~np.isin(point, r).all(axis=1)

sampled_points = point[non_building_mask]
new_file = laspy.create(point_format=las.header.point_format, file_version=las.header.version)
new_file.x, new_file.y, new_file.z = sampled_points.T


Does r contain one point or many?

A [mcve] with iterative solution would help.  As for your isin approach, have you examined the result of that isin step?  Show that.

I guess this code work for you. This code find index point array, you can remove matching_indices from your point.
# We create a special view type to compare the first and second sequence in lexicographic order
dtype = np.dtype((np.void, point.dtype.itemsize * point.shape[1]))
array1_view = point.view(dtype)
array2_view = r.view(dtype)

# Find indexes of matching rows
matching_indices = np.where(np.in1d(array1_view, array2_view))[0]


assuming both r and point have a shape like (x, 3)
bad_points_indices = np.any(point==r[:,np.newaxis,:], axis=(0,2))

